# Aria2 rpc secret token format?

Tags: rpc, aria2

Aria2c rpc user-password authorization marked as deprecated, it is suggested to use [security token](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#rpc-auth), but what is the format of that token? Is it like password or what?

Comment: rewritten question fully

Comment: There is no Java in aria2c implementation, I'm asking about the format of token string, not how it sent via rpc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this issue https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/294 I'm assuming, that token is same thing as password -- plain text, without any formatting, but it does not require user name.